# Access Azure DevOps API from an Electron application using Azure AD OAuth 2.0

Tags: azure, azure-devops, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to implement the OAuth 2.0 authentication (Bearer JWT token) from an Electron application in order to access Azure DevOps APIs (repos, work items, test plans).

The Azure DevOps organization is AAD-backed so I'm trying to access the Azure DevOps API using the access token given by Azure AD /token endpoint.

I'm using the Authorization code flow with PKCE to obtain the token.

However, when accessing the Azure DevOps API, I'm constantly seeing error messages regarding the wrong scope.

`The scope is invalid`

With curl calls, I see the following:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://spsprodcus2.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=dev.azure.com&amp;reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2FXXXXXXX%2FXXXXX%2F_apis%2Fwit%2Fworkitems%3Fids%3D11016%252C54321%26api-version%3D6.0&amp;redirect=1&amp;hid=1b2cef85-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-8b6420bc5933&amp;context=eyJodCI6XXXXXXXXXXXXLCJjcyI6IiJ90#ctx=eyJTaWduSW5XXXXXXW5lLmNvbSJdfQ2">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Of course, my AAD-registered application has Azure DevOps API permissions added:

[image]

I have tried another option - obtaining the token from Azure DevOps-backed app registration created here: https://aex.dev.azure.com/app/register but then the following error is shown:

`The corresponding application isn't registered within the Azure AD tenant.`

Nevertheless, I see that applications registered with the Azure DevOps portal aren't shown in the Azure AD applications list.

Thus I start thinking that either the Authorization code flow with PKCE  for Azure DevOps should be different (in terms of API calls) or there's something wrong with the Azure AD application (e.g. scopes or API permissions).

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

To access the Azure DevOps, make sure to create **Azure AD application** and add the permission consented like below:

[image]

Use the below endpoint to generate the **`code`** for the Authorization code+PKCE flow:

Make sure to use **scope** as **`499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/user_impersonation`**

```json
GET
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?  
response_type=code  
&client_id=ClientID
&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/user_impersonation
&redirect_uri=RedirectUro
&code_challenge=CodeChallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

When you hit the above endpoint, the **code** will be generated like below:

[image]

**To generate the token, make use of below parameters:**

```json
GET
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:client_id
grant_type:authorization_code
code:codegeneratedabove
redirect_uri:redirect_uri
code_verifier:S256
scope:499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/user_impersonation
client_secret:client_secret
```

**Response:**

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/7YY15ap.png)]

To access the Azure DevOps, make use of the above generated access token.

***I am able to get the Azure DevOps account details successfully like below:***

```json
GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=6.0
```

[image]

*Based on your requirement, you can fetch the details from Azure DevOps from the token.*