# why ...dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryid}/stats/branches?api-version=7.0 doesn't work on postman?

Tags: git, azure, url, postman

I have already tried to connect and check what I am receiving on Postman, but it consistently returns a "401 Unauthorized" status, even when I am within the network or organization..
[image]
However, when I access the URL using my browser (Chrome, Firefox, or Edge), I can see a JSON response, though it doesn't seem to be useful.
[image]

It appears that any browser or other PCs/accounts/servers work fine. This issue might be related to a proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I got the **same error** when I passed invalid password value while fetching the data:

For *sample*:

```json
https://dev.azure.com/devOpsdemo/proj1/_apis?api-version=7.0
```

[image]

But when I run the **URL in browser**, I got the response:

[image]

The error usually occurs if you are passing invalid values in Basic Auth tab.

**To resolve the error,** generate a **PAT token** in Azure DevOps portal:

**In Azure DevOps Portal -> Go to Profile - Personal Access Token* -> New Token and then click on Create*

[image]

The PAT token will get generated:

[image]

When I passed the PAT token in Basic Auth, **I got the response successfully** (*an empty response as I don't have apis configured*):

***Pass the PAT token in the password tab and leave UserName as empty like below:***

```json
https://dev.azure.com/devOpsdemo/proj1/_apis?api-version=7.0
```

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can also make use of Azure Active Directory Authentication and call the API. Refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74080759/access-azure-devops-api-from-an-electron-application-using-azure-ad-oauth-2-0/74095914#74095914) by me.

**Reference:**

[Call Azure DevOps REST API with Postman](https://www.sanderh.dev/call-Azure-DevOps-REST-API-Postman/) by Sander Holvoet